# Spring EL - split a property value and get the second entry

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-el

I have the following property in my properties

```
test.property=context:test:sample
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value "`test`" by doing a split with `colon(:)` and getting the second part.

I'm doing this:

```
@Value("#{'${test.property}'.split(':')[1]}")
private String test;
```

However, it seems to come up as `null`. Is there something wrong in what I'm doing? I have other properties being injected in the same file and they seem to be read without a problem. Even if I replace the expression above with just a `@Value("${test.property}")`, it seems to read the string `context:test:sample`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have works fine for me (I just tested it); you must have some other problem with your configuration. Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and watch all the injection processing.